# Disable input conditionally (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, input

I have an input:

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="name" 
  class="form-control" 
  name="name"  
  v-model="form.name" 
  :disabled="validated ? '' : disabled"
/>
```

and in my Vue.js component, I have:

```js
..
..
ready() {
  this.form.name = this.store.name;
  this.form.validated = this.store.validated;
},
..
```

`validated` being a `boolean`, it can be either `0` or `1`, but no matter what value is stored in the database, my input is always disabled.

I need the input to be disabled if `false`, otherwise it should be enabled and editable.

Update:

Doing this always **enables** the input (no matter I have 0 or 1 in the database):

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="name" 
  class="form-control" 
  name="name" 
  v-model="form.name" 
  :disabled="validated ? '' : disabled"
/>
```

Doing this always **disabled** the input (no matter I have 0 or 1 in  the database):

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="name" 
  class="form-control" 
  name="name" 
  v-model="form.name" 
  :disabled="validated ? disabled : ''"
/>
```

Answer (score 701, accepted):

To remove the disabled prop, you should set its value to `false`. This needs to be the boolean value for `false`, not the string `'false'`.

So, if the value for `validated` is either a 1 or a 0, then conditionally set the `disabled` prop based off that value. E.g.:

```
<input type="text" :disabled="validated == 1">
```

Here is an example.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    disabled: 0
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="disabled = (disabled + 1) % 2">Toggle Enable</button>
  <input type="text" :disabled="disabled == 1">
    
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: in my db, I have 0 and 1 stored for true and false, playing with your fiddle, 0 and 1 keeps it disabled

Comment: do I need to edit my db structure make it exactly true and false?

Comment: No, just set the value to either `true` or `false` depending on the value of the item in your db

Comment: I've updated to the fiddle to show how to do it with numbers

Comment: sorry, but may be its laravel, you code makes complete sense, but still, I have a `boolean` field set `Default` to `0`, in database, the respective field shows as `tinyint(1)`, changing its values from `0' to '1` doesnt change the status, no clue why

Comment: Try displaying the value of your `validated` variable to help debug. Insert `{{ typeof disabled }} {{ disabled }}` above the input. It should display `number 1` if the value is 1, or `number 0` if the value is zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115892/discussion-between-zaffar-saffee-and-asemahle).

Comment: The code could be cleaner: You don't need to assign 1 or 0, just play around with true/false like : @Sebastiao Marcos check this out :

https://jsfiddle.net/eo8kd2wd/13/

Comment: just do : :disabled="validated" 

As long as validated is True/false or 0/1, Javascript will know.

Comment: @Despertaweb  Not always, if the database provides the 1/0 as a string because of a bad translation layer, `"0"` is just true, unless you cast it to a number first

Comment: Then just make sure to get the type you want. ;)

Comment: broken jsfiddle link

Comment: @gk the code that was in the jsfiddle is now in the answer

Answer (score 90):

you could have a computed property that returns a boolean dependent on whatever criteria you need.

```html
<input type="text" :disabled=isDisabled>
```

then put your logic in a computed property...

```js
computed: {
  isDisabled() {
    // evaluate whatever you need to determine disabled here...
    return this.form.validated;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, no quotes needed, in my case calling `isDisabled()` within the HTML, defined in `Data`.

Answer (score 30):

Not difficult, check this.

```html
<button @click="disabled = !disabled">Toggle Enable</button>
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name"  v-model="form.name" :disabled="disabled">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo8kd2wd/13/)

Answer (score 18):

Your disabled attribute requires a boolean value:

`<input :disabled="validated" />`

Notice how i've only checked if `validated` - This should work as `0 is falsey` ...e.g

`0 is considered to be false in JS (like undefined or null)`

`1 is in fact considered to be true`

To be extra careful try:
`<input :disabled="!!validated" />`

This double negation turns the `falsey` or `truthy` value of `0` or `1` to `false` or `true`

don't believe me? go into your console and type `!!0` or `!!1` :-)

Also, to make sure your number `1` or `0` are definitely coming through as a Number and not the String `'1'` or `'0'` pre-pend the value you are checking with a `+` e.g `<input :disabled="!!+validated"/>` this turns a string of a number into a Number e.g

`+1 = 1
+'1' = 1`

Like David Morrow said above you could put your conditional logic into a method - this gives you more **readable** code - just return out of the method the condition you wish to check.

Comment: People have given a lot of complicated answers here, when `!!` really simplifies it a lot

Answer (score 18):

You can manipulate `:disabled` attribute in **vue.js**.

It will accept a boolean, if it's **true**, then the input gets disabled, otherwise it will be enabled...

Something like structured like below in your case for example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" v-model="form.name" :disabled="validated ? false : true">
```

Also read this below:

> #### Conditionally Disabling Input Elements via JavaScript
>   Expression
>
> You can conditionally disable input elements inline
>   with a JavaScript expression. This compact approach provides a quick
>   way to apply simple conditional logic. For example, if you only needed
>   to check the length of the password, you may consider doing something
>   like this.

```
<h3>Change Your Password</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="newPassword">Please choose a new password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newPassword" placeholder="Password" v-model="newPassword">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="confirmPassword">Please confirm your new password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password" v-model="confirmPassword" v-bind:disabled="newPassword.length === 0 ? true : false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You may make a computed property and enable/disable any form type according to its value.

```
<template>
    <button class="btn btn-default" :disabled="clickable">Click me</button>
</template>
<script>
     export default{
          computed: {
              clickable() {
                  // if something
                  return true;
              }
          }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me. to move the method to computed instead of methods. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

To toggle the input's ***disabled*** attribute was surprisingly complex.  The issue for me was twofold:

**(1)**  Remember: *in HTML* the input's "disabled" attribute is **NOT a Boolean** attribute.
The mere **presence** of the attribute means that **the input is disabled.**

However, the Vue.js creators have prepared this...
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

(Thanks to @connexo for this... [How to add disabled attribute in input text in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194163/how-to-add-disabled-attribute-in-input-text-in-vuejs/49194596#49194596))

**(2)** In addition, there was a DOM timing re-rendering issue that I was having.  The DOM was not updating when I tried to toggle back.

Upon certain situations, "the component will not re-render immediately. It will update in the next 'tick.'"

From Vue.js docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

The solution was to use:

```
this.$nextTick(()=>{
    this.disableInputBool = true
})
```

Fuller example workflow:

```
<div @click="allowInputOverwrite">
    <input
        type="text"
        :disabled="disableInputBool">
</div>

<button @click="disallowInputOverwrite">
    press me (do stuff in method, then disable input bool again)
</button>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      disableInputBool: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    allowInputOverwrite(){
      this.disableInputBool = false
    },
    disallowInputOverwrite(){
      // accomplish other stuff here.
      this.$nextTick(()=>{
        this.disableInputBool = true
      })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: ++ (However, the Vue.js creators have prepared this... https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
 <div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms' /> Click me to enable
    </label>
  </p>
  <input :disabled='isDisabled'></input>
</div>
```

vue js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    terms: false
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to put function parenthesis
<input :disabled='isDisabled()'></input>

Answer (score 3):

Can use this add condition.

```
  <el-form-item :label="Amount ($)" style="width:100%"  >
            <template slot-scope="scoped">
            <el-input-number v-model="listQuery.refAmount" :disabled="(rowData.status !== 1 ) === true" ></el-input-number>
            </template>
          </el-form-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use SFC and want a minimal example for this case, this would be how you can use it:

```js
export default {
  data() {
return {
  disableInput: false
}
  },
  methods: {
toggleInput() {
  this.disableInput = !this.disableInput
}
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
<input type="text" :disabled="disableInput">
<button @click="toggleInput">Toggle Input</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Clicking the `button` triggers the `toggleInput` function and simply switches the state of `disableInput` with `this.disableInput = !this.disableInput`.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name"  v-model="form.name" :disabled="!validated">
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution:

// App.vue **Template**:

```
<button
            type="submit"
            class="disabled:opacity-50 w-full px-3 py-4 text-white bg-indigo-500 rounded-md focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none"
            :disabled="isButtonDisabled()"
            @click="sendIdentity()"
          >
            <span v-if="MYVARIABLE > 0"> Add {{ MYVARIABLE }}</span>
            <span v-else-if="MYVARIABLE == 0">Alternative text if you like</span>
            <span v-else>Alternative text if you like</span>
          </button>
```

*Styles based on [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/)*

// App.vue **Script**:

```
 (...)
  methods: {
   isButtonDisabled(){
    return this.MYVARIABLE >= 0 ? undefined: 'disabled';
   }
 }
```

Manual:
[vue v2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)
[vue v3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#attributes)

> If isButtonDisabled has the value of null, undefined, or false, the
> disabled attribute will not even be included in the rendered 
> element.

Comment: You should precise in what way your answer enhances existing answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828642/3641635)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55946562/3641635). The template way seems useful here, you should give more details in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that ES6 Sets/Maps don't appear to be reactive as far as i can tell, at time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

We can disable inputs conditionally with `Vue 3` by setting the disabled prop to the condition when we want to `disable` the `input`

**For instance, we can write:**

```
<template>
  <input :disabled="disabled" />
  <button @click="disabled = !disabled">toggle disable</button>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      disabled: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something newly released called [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert), which is literally making it ignored by the browser.

```html
<template>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    id="name" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="name"  
    :inert="isItInert"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
const isItInert = true
</script>
```

Here is [the playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kM1uwzAIgF/F4tzY9yittGPfwRcvJZur+EdAuk1V3n24q7Jqk3qDD/iMucJLrfayIPQwCKY6B8GDz8YMMddFTAuNka+Kew+Cn+LhzuJJSQ4JNzLOgVnhVCh1Y8lCZd6KrfN34A77mJFEceSjHFvsoVWcrjC4h3005ZFiFcMoS1WifhazzZm9mcLM2OZ+Og+wg5hqIelSqPbMJesnr02v790K7KE3N9KYXqHlHt5FKvfO8TS205zZFnpzGllassSEFjl1r1Q+GEnFHnYPDqfwgtQR5hMS0jPnn9Z/3qZdfV5h/QbLMY/2) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Vue 3

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="name" 
  class="form-control" 
  name="name"  
  v-model="form.name" 
  :disabled="VALIDATOR == '0'"
/>
```