# VueJS: clicking disabled button still changes route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to disable a button when `currentpage` is `firstpage`:

[image]

The button disables correctly but the route still changes when it is clicked.

**javascript**

```
checkDisable() {
  if (this.currentPage==1) {
    document.getElementById("previousBtn").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

**vue js**

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'products', params: {page: currentPage-1 }}">
   <button id="previousBtn" class="btn btn-default" v-bind="checkDisable()">
     Previous
   </button>
</router-link>
```

Comment: Did you debug that? What is the value of `this.currentPage`?

Comment: you need the `function` keyword before `checkDisable`. Please look at the console.

Comment: value of this.currentPage is 1

Comment: Are you sure it is button that is "clickable" not `<a>` from `router-link`

Comment: Stop doing DOM manipulation. That's what Vue is for. [Use `v-bind` to set disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38085541/392102).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vue.js disable input conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085180/vue-js-disable-input-conditionally)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using `v-bind` correctly. It would be simplest to add a  `disabled` attribute to your button and bind it to an inline function that simply returns true if the value of `currentPage` is `1`:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" :disabled="currentPage == 1">
  Previous
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code. Basically the button is disabled or non-clickable, it is clickable by the  tag. So you just need to non-clickable to this as simply like this:

```
checkDisable() {
if (this.currentPage==1) {
     var obj  = document.getElementById("previousBtn");
     obj.disabled = true;
     obj.parentElement.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: it still clickable

Answer (score 0):

Your button is wrapped in a `router-link` this is essentially an `anchor` tag... If your button is disabled - it is still wrapped in a `router-link`

Isn't the `anchor (router-link)` still going to be the target of your click?

Also best to use `:disabled` as an attribute instead of manipulating/querying the DOM.

`<button :disabled="shouldBeDisabled"></button>`
Maybe look further into `vue-router` you may be able to disable the `router-link` attribute similar to the button. (granted disabled button is proabable being styled...) so do both...

I know that there is an attribute you can pass to a `router-link` called exact which evaluates to true if the route is consistent with the route the `router-link` 'links to.

You could check for the exact property maybe? this could eliminate the need for the `currentPage` check

You could pass a class of `.button` to your `router-link` and style it up like a button... this would eliminate the need for the use of a `button` that is behaving like an `anchor`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I had to get rid of the router-link and add a method that programmatically changed the route.

`<button id="previousBtn" class="btn btn-default" @click="changeRoute">
   Previous
 </button>`

```
methods: {
  changeRoute () {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'name-of-route' })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a data `disabled` that's `true` when the button is disabled:

```
data() {
    return {
       disabled: true
    }
}
```

Now the click only change the route when `disabled == false`:

```
@click="disabled ? null : this.$router.push({ name: "mypage" });"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this code, i hope can help somemany people.

```
<router-link
   :to="btn.back.disabled ? '' : '/dashboard'"
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-secondary mr-2"
>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this 
JS:

```
checkDisable() {
if (this.currentPage-1) {
return true;
}
}
```

vue js:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'products', params: {page: currentPage-1 }}">
<button id="previousBtn" class="btn btn-default" disabled="checkDisable()">
Previous
</button>
</router-link>
```