# Disable form input in the next page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm busy with creating a single page application. I have an input form for different proposes. 
When **user 1** fills the form, I want him to save it and let **user 2** fill his part of the form on the page that is created for user 2. But the **input** of user 1 should be **disabled** for user 2, user 2 should've only read rights.

I hope you understand my question and if something is needed, please let me know.

I've to work with vuejs, bootstrap-vue and javascript.

Comment: Sigh.  Please read [ask] and then create a [mcve]

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To remove the disabled prop, you should set its value to false.

So, if the value for validated is either a 1 or a 0, then conditionally set the disabled prop based off that value. E.g.:

Here is an example.

Credits: [vue.js disable input conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085180/vue-js-disable-input-conditionally)

Comment: tnx mate, it opened my eyes...

Comment: np. the example: https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/eo8kd2wd/