# How to make input read only based on particular value in Vue?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

How to make an input field read only based on Vue data?

For example:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="selectCategory" 
        :disabled="cat_id >= 
            1" 
        name="cat_id">
```

I want to make the field read only but not disabled. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085180/vue-js-disable-input-conditionally

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Please note that, according to HTML specs, the select tag in HTML doesn't have a readonly attribute.

However, in general case, I'd go with something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="selectCategory" :readonly="cat_id >= 1">
```

Basically, the documentation says that if an attribute value evaluates to false, then the attribute being omitted. See [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) for further details.

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this:

```
<input v-bind:readonly="isReadOnly">
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue while making a form for a password changing form and I encountered the browser trying to autocomplete everything. This should prevent the autocomplete from firing and also provide a method to change the value to suit your needs.
For some reason adding a v-bind:readonly property of true reverts to readonly="readonly"
Here is my currently working example which removes and re-adds the readonly property on focusout.

Vue Template HTML

```
<input type="password" v-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" @focusin="toggleReadonly" @focusout="toggleReadonly" :readonly="true">
```

Method

```
toggleReadonly(event){
          event.preventDefault()
          if(event.target.getAttribute('readonly') == 'readonly'){
              event.target.removeAttribute('readonly')
          }
          else{
              event.target.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly')
         }
 }
```

Comment: autocomplete="off" for preventing an input to autocomplete

Comment: <input type="password" v-model="user.password" placeholder="Password"  autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 1):

you could have a computed property that returns a boolean dependent on whatever criteria you need.

```
<input type="text" :disabled=isDisabled>
```

then put your logic in a computed property...

```
computed: {
 isDisabled() {
// evaluate whatever you need to determine disabled here...
   return true;
 }
}
```

JSFIDDLE 
https://jsfiddle.net/sureshamk/0dzvcf4d/1320/

Comment: Disabled is not the same as readonly. A disabled field in a form won't be submitted while a readonly will be. Further, CSS styles are not the same for readonly and disabled.