# How to add disabled attribute in input text in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have 2 urls

- `/register`
- `/register?sponsor=4`

The `/register` route will give me a clean input text in which I can type everything
and the second route will bring a the same input but it has a value of 4 and it's disabled so users cannot modify it.
I managed to get params from router dynamic using vue-router and everything is fine,
but when I visit `/register` I get the clean input but as soon as I start typing the input will be disabled and I can only type one character.
This what I tried so far,
**HTML :**

```
<input :disabled="sponsor ? true : false" v-model="sponsor" id="sponsor" type="number" class="form-control" name="sponsor" value="" required tabindex="14">
```

**Javascript vuejs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: []
    });
    new Vue({
        router,
        el: '#app',
        data () {
            return {
                cities: [],
                city: '',
                selectedCountry: '',
                sponsor: null
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            if (this.$route.query.sponsor) {
                this.sponsor = this.$route.query.sponsor
                console.log(this.sponsor)
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onChangeCountry() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/cities/country/' + this.selectedCountry)
                .then(response => this.cities = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are binding the input value to sponsor with `v-model="sponsor"`, so when you star typing, the sponsor get the value and disable the input,

you have to set a flag to know if the value of sponsor comes from the route, and apply the disable logic with that flag. Or directly use the `$route.query.sponsor` on the `:disabled` (`:disabled="$route.query.sponsor"`)

```
<input :disabled="isFromRoute" v-model="sponsor" />

mounted: function() {
  if (this.$route.query.sponsor) {
    this.sponsor = this.$route.query.sponsor
    this.isFromRoute = true //set the flag, make sure to have it in your data section
  }
},
```

Answer (score 6):

`disabled` is ***not a Boolean*** attribute.

The mere **presence** of the attribute means that **the input is disabled**.

The only allowed attribute values for disabled are `"disabled"` and `""`.

So these three variations are legal to create a disabled input:

```
<input disabled ... />
```

or

```
<input disabled="" ... />
```

or

```
<input disabled="disabled" ... />
```

If you do

```
<input disabled="false" ... />
```

that will still disable the input simply because the attribute `disabled` is on it - on top of being invalid HTML because of an illegal attribute value.

Check it out here:

```html
<input type="text" disabled="false" />
```

*So to solve your problem you need to find a way to not create the attribute on the input in case you don't want to disable it.*

### Edit: Turns out Vue.js creators have prepared this:

> In the case of boolean attributes, where their mere existence implies true, v-bind works a little differently. In this example:
>
> ```
> <button v-bind:disabled="isButtonDisabled">Button</button>
> ```
>
> If isButtonDisabled has the value of null, undefined, or false, the disabled attribute will not even be included in the rendered  element.
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Comment: this.$nextTick() was necessary for me as well. From: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html  @connexo, I Used your answer as part of my a response. Thank you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085180/vue-js-disable-input-conditionally/54834317#54834317

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<input :disabled="$route.query.sponsor ? true : false" v-model="sponsor" id="sponsor" type="number" class="form-control" name="sponsor" value="" required tabindex="14">
```