# Computed property not disabling input

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to set the disabled property on a text field via checkbox.  I'm referencing [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085180/disable-input-conditionally-vue-js), but none of the solutions are working for me.

My text field and checkbox are as follows:

```
      <input
        type="checkbox"                  
        class="form-check-input"
        v-model="formData.useSystemSetting"            
      >


     <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      :class="hasError('maxCount') ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
      placeholder="Enter the Maximum Count"
      v-model="formData.maxCount"
      :disabled = "isDisabled"
    >
```

My computed property is:

```
computed:{
 isDisabled: function() {      
  this.useSystemSetting = this.useSystemSetting == true?false:true
  return this.useSystemSetting;
},
```

I'm also setting useSystemSettings in the data section to true because if I don't it doesn't get populated.  When I add a breakpoint to the computed property, it's only getting hit on the page load, but not after.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed to mutate other properties inside the computed property, you should only do some process and return a value:

```js
computed:{
  isDisabled: function() { 
    return this.useSystemSetting ? false : true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still not working.  The function only seems to be getting hit upon page load, not when  I check the box on and off.

Comment: it should be bound to `formData.useSystemSetting` like ` return this.formData.useSystemSetting ? false : true;`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mutate data inside a computed property.
A computed property is used whenever you need to use logic for getting a value which includes reactive data, as you'd find [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html).

You could try something like:

```
computed:{
  isDisabled: function() { 
    return !this.formData.useSystemSetting;
  }
}
```

Presuming that the formData object will not be null at this point.
To prevent that, you could also use something like:

```
return ((this.formData || {}).useSystemSetting || true) ? false : true;
```